# where to save a php page which will communicate between the MySql database and the android application?

Tags: android

I have been reading the tutorial shown on various websites on connecting a MySQL database using php to android. **I dont know where to "put" save my php page which will communicate between the  MySql database and the android application.**
can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without you showing the tutorial it's obviously guesswork, but I suspect they talk about a server (with mysql) and an app.

The php page runs on the server (or another server that has access to the mysql server).

You put it on the web-directy on that server, which should run a webserver (apache for instance) next to the mysql server it should run.

Answer (score 0):

I run a VPS which runs MSSQL server and runs a web service in .NET which I host on a domain. My Android code then calls this domain/web service.

PHP would be the same. You'd host your .php file on a web server somewhere that you can access.

Answer (score 0):

Recently we have implemented this in one of our apps. PHP script/page resides on your hosting server, using this php script/page you will communicate with mysql database and returns the response as Json string. In app, you need to use HttpClient to invoke your php page/script. Then use JsonObject to parse the json response.